# How can I do an IF statement for the homepage?

Tags: if-statement, bigcommerce

I've recently discovered how to have if/thens trigger if it's a category vs a product page. Can this be done for the homepage? I'm trying to set a couple of custom meta tags but only on the homepage via the base.html file.

I've already tried {{#if home }} and {{#if homepage }} with no success. Thoughts?

Examples:

```
    {{#if product }}
    <do a thing on product pages>
    {{/if}}

    {{#if category }}
    <do a thing on category pages>
    {{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the current template:

```
{{#if template '==' 'pages/home'}}
   ...
{{/if}}
```